# Remove unique values from array

Tags: java, arrays, groovy

Example array: [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,12,13,7,4]

I want to keep only values which has more than one. Thus final outcome I am expecting is [4,4,4,7,7]

I could find duplicates as follows. But how can I reverse this? Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) { 
    for (int j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++) { 
        if (names[i].equals(names[j]) ) { 
            // got the duplicate element 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just save all the duplicates in an array/a list. Then use another loop to remove the ones in the list from the original array

Comment: Why is this tagged Java and groovy?  Which do you want?

Comment: @tim_yates Writing this in Groovy but a Java solution works as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this in Groovy:

```
def result = names.countBy { it }
                  .findAll { k, v -> v > 1 }
                  .collect { k, v -> [k] * v }
                  .flatten()
```

Or

```
def result = names - names.countBy { it }.findAll { k, v -> v == 1 }.keySet()
```

Answer (score 2):

Groovy Solution
I like *@tim_yates* solution but here is another solution:

```
def result = names.findAll{ names.count(it) > 1}
```

Comment: dsharew, simple and nice. OP has given expected output. applying `.sort()` on **findAll** can yield the same result.

Answer (score 1):

And of course there is a solution using Java 8 Streams ....

```
        int[] ia = {1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,12,13,7,4};
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(ia).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        ia = list.stream()
                 .filter(x -> Collections.frequency(list, x) > 1)
                 .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-optimal idea:

```
Integer count;
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) { 
    count = 0;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++) { 
        if (names[i].equals(names[j]) ) { 
            count++;
        } 
    } 
    if(count == 1){
        count = 0;
        ArrayUtils.removeElement(names, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement You could simply create a new linkedList to store the duplicated elements and use java.collections to change from Linked list to array

Answer (score 0):

You can also `groupBy` the identity, take the values, keep only those with a size greater one, concat the results:

```
[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,12,13,7,4]
    .groupBy()
    .values()
    .findAll{it.size()>1}
    .sum()
// [4, 4, 4, 7, 7]
```